# Ayuda Unity 3d no me reconoce la comparación &&

Tags: unity2d

Estoy en medio de un proyecto y al hacer la comparacion && no me la acepta como comparacion si no como variable, ayuda por favor

```
          //comienza el juego
            if (gameState == (GameState.Idle && (Input.GetKeyDown("up") || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)))){
                gameState = GameState.playting;
            }
                    else if(GameState == GameState.Playing){

        float finalSpeed = parallaxSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        backgraund.uvRect  = new Rect(backgraund.uvRect.x + finalSpeed, 0f, 1f,1f);
        plantforn.uvRect  = new Rect(plantforn.uvRect.x + finalSpeed * 4, 0f, 1f,1f);
```

Comment: Que error te da ?Estas seguro que estas comparando cosas iguales y no peras con manzanas?

Comment: error cs0019:operator && cannot be applied to operant

Comment: Creo que tienes el if un poco raro que es lo que esperas que haga?

Comment: iniciar el juego una vez se pulse la flecha hacia arriba o le den click

Comment: (gameState == GameState.Idle && (Input.GetKeyDown("up") || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))) Compronaria que gameState sea IDLE y ademas que se pulse la flecha de arriba o el click

Answer (score 0):

Prueba la condición así:

```
if ((gameState == GameState.Idle) && (Input.GetKeyDown("up") || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)))
```

Diría que `GameState.Idle` es un `int`, así que probablemente se queje de que no puedes hacer un `&&` de `int` y `bool`.

La condición es equivalente a la que tienes. Si el estado es `Idle`, y se está presionando la flecha de arriba o haciendo click, entonces entra en el if.

En cualquier caso, esto como tienes tú `(GameState.Idle && (Input.GetKeyDown("up") || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)))` devolvería un `bool` es decir, verdadero o falso, y entonces estarías comprobando `gameState == true/false`, lo cual no creo que funcionara tampoco, imagino que `gameState` es un `int`.